# How to write code for a function which will return 2 values and write to excel when it is called?

Tags: vbscript

My question is how can I return 2 values (`Sales_Tax_Amount` & `Total_Price`) from a function.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim Sale_Amount, Sales_Tax_Rate, Sales_Tax_Amount, Total_Price
Dim MySheet, RowCount, i

'Create connection b/w UFT and Excel
Set MyExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
MyExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\PIIT\Desktop\UFT\BootCamp2\BootCamp2 Question 4.xlsx"
MyExcel.Application.Visible = True
Set MySheet = MyExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ("Sheet1")
RowCount = MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To RowCount
    'Read Values from Excel
    Sale_Amount = MySheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
    Sales_Tax_Rate = MySheet.Cells(i, "B").Value

    'Call Function
    fnTax_Calculator
Next

Function fnTax_Calculator()
    Dim Arry(1)
    'Function should return Sales_Tax_Amount when it is called in the form of %x.xx
    Sales_Tax_Amount = Sale_Amount * Sales_Tax_Rate
    'Function should return Total_Price when it is called in the form of $xxxx.xx
    Total_Price = Sale_Amount + Sales_Tax_Amount

    Arry(0) = Sales_Tax_Amount
    Arry(1) = Total_Price
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck. (Oh, and to answer the question you asked: You use your keyboard.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am very new to Stack Overflow. I Just joined and post a question. I have no idea how it works. Anyway Thanks

Comment: When you created your account, it was suggested that you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before posting here. I'd take that suggestion before you ask your next question.

Comment: You can change the parameters that are passed in are they are passed ByRef (pass a param solely to be changed). Or return a two element array.

Comment: Hopefully now someone can help me to write the function.

Comment: Your question says you want to return 2 values, but the comments in your code say you want to return either `Sales_Tax_Amount` or `Total_Price` depending on how it's called? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers.  The thing is i want to write the function in such a way that it should return both Sales_Tax_Amount(%x.xx) and Total_Price($xxxx.xx) when it is called .

Answer (score 0):

A function can't have two returns, BUT it can return a variable type that can hold more than one value like an Array. It can also have variables passed to it `byref`, change the variables values, and the originally calling subroutine can then use those changed values:

Return an array that contains the two values:

```
Sub test()
    myArray = myFunction
    Debug.Print myArray(0), myArray(1)
End Sub
Function myFunction() As Variant
    Dim returnVals(0 To 1) As Double

    returnVals(0) = 1.36
    returnVals(1) = 2.5

    myFunction = returnVals
End Function
```

Running subroutine "test()" will print the following values to the immediate pane

```
 1.36          2.5
```

Alternatively you can pass in two variables `byref`. The function will change their values and the subroutine that passed the variables will be able to use the changed values after the function runs.

```
Sub test()
    Dim var1 As Double
    Dim var2 As Double

    Call mySub(var1, var2)

    Debug.Print var1, var2
End Sub

Function mySub(ByRef variable1 As Double, ByRef variable2 As Double)
    variable1 = 1.36
    variable2 = 2.5
End Function
```

This will print out the values set in the function to the immediate window.

You could also store the values determined in the function out to a sheet and pick them up in the subroutine, or store the values in a global variable. Both of these should be avoided though unless you are going to use these values over and over again and need them to be persistent between vba runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `fnTax_Calculator()` would 'work', if you'd assign the array to the function name:

```
Dim a : a = fnTax_Calculator()
WScript.Echo Join(a)

Function fnTax_Calculator()
    Dim Arry(1)
    'Function should return Sales_Tax_Amount when it is called in the form of %x.xx
    'Sales_Tax_Amount = Sale_Amount * Sales_Tax_Rate
    'Function should return Total_Price when it is called in the form of $xxxx.xx
    'Total_Price = Sale_Amount + Sales_Tax_Amount

    Arry(0) = 47 ' Sales_Tax_Amount
    Arry(1) = 11 ' Total_Price
    ' to specify the return value, assign it to the function's name
    fnTax_Calculator = Arry
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 48654959.vbs
47 11
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: After applying your suggestions my function is working fine,